# Is tipping a form of tzedakah?

Tags: tzedakah-charity

In these times when people who work need every dollar is tipping a form of tzedakah?

Comment: Tzedaka is for people in need. Do most waiters qualify?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Gifts_to_the_Poor.10.7?with=Commentary&lang=bi  This answer applies here as well